# SVN: why is it always necessary to merge before checking in if your file is out of date?

Tags: svn, merge, automerge

Consider the following scenario:

Hally and Sarry both check out the same revision of file A.

Both make some changes to A.

Hally checks in first, no drama.

Sarry then tries to check in; gets told her file A is out of date and she needs to merge the latest version from repository with her locally changed A before she can check in her changes.

My question:

This is only necessary if there's conflicts between Hally and Sarry's changes. If there's no conflict, SVN should just allow Sarry to check in anyway, auto merging Sarry's changes with the repository version and print a message saying:"your A was outdated, but SVN detected no conflicts and thus performed auto merge and check in".

I'm a little dissatisfied that SVN always forces you to manually update and merge even when there's no conflicts.

Comment: Updated is needed so that the comparison between files can be made by the client machine. You will always upload the latest version.

Comment: SVN can't compare to see if the changes can be merged without conflict until you update the working copy. Read the SVN book section on merging.

Answer (score 0):

Sarry simply needs to take a svn up, if there are no conflicts merge happens automatically. Only if both of them changes same lines differently would she be asked to help with the merge.